Why does my cv2.imread() giving me None? (python)
I am new to this image detection thing and I've been following a youtube video and trying to make a program that detects an image so I can automate some fishing in a game. BUT I keep getting this error where everytime i made a correct path to the image file i keep getting None output. Could somebody help me with this please?
from numpy import asarray
from mss import mss
import cv2
import time
import pyautogui
import imageio.v3 as iio

import os
import shutil

def vision():
    cords = (400,400,1100,400)
    mark = cv2.imread("D:\\Python\\New folder\\apple.png")

    print(cv2.imshow("OpenCV Image",mark))
    
while True:
    vision()    

My screenshot of the output:

expected the image to be read but when i recall it, it wont work.

Hi, could you please show an error message? What exactly do you mean by "can't recall the image?"

You need to call waitKey() after imshow().

cv2.imshow doesn't return any value, so when you call print(cv2.imshow(...)) you get None.

this doesn't need imshow at all for the [mre]. just an imread and an assertion that the result isn't None

@ChristophRackwitz I am not even sure the image returned from imread (mark) is None here. I think the "None"s we see in the terminal is because the OP attempts to print the "result" of imshow.

the title itself says imread() but the code doesn't address this... instead it's about imshow()... confusing question.

Did minor edits to your code to make it workable.
What was happening:

function cv2.imshow(...) doesn't return anything. Thus if you try to wrap it into print you'll see 'None' in the terminal. So the image was processed by cv2, but you only saw None in the outputs. Consider replacing print(cv2.imshow(..)) with cv2.imshow(..).
You were running function vision multiple times in the while loop. This triggered printing None multiple times. Not sure that this is what you wanted to do, I would propose to eliminate this loop.
After calling cv2.imgshow(..) you need to additionally call cv2.waitKey(...), this will make image appear on the screen.

import cv2

flag_vision = False

def vision():
    cords = (400,400,1100,400)
    mark = cv2.imread("D:\\Python\\New folder\\apple.png")
    cv2.imshow("OpenCV Image",mark)
    cv2.waitKey(0) 



while True:
   if not flag_vision:
        # prevents function `vision` from running multiple times.
        vision()
        flag_vision = True


you sound like you think imread() is always supposed to return None ("So the image was processed by cv2"). that's wrong. you don't seem to be familiar with that part of OpenCV, to say the least. your answer doesn't address the issue of imread() not reading the file (i.e. returning None instead). rephrasing the question or prettying up the code isn't an answer. this answer shouldn't have been upvoted.

Thx for the comment. 1) I didn't say that imread returns None. 2) I said that imshow returns none. You can see this from function typing hints. 3) I have checked what error will be returned by cv2.imshow if the path to the image is incorrect. And if path is incorrect cv2.imshow doesn't return None and triggers an Exception. 4) I'm not asking You to upvote my answer or to accept it. Hope this clarifies the answer.

you're absolutely right. my mistake. I'm sorry. I didn't read carefully and mistook your mention of imshow for imread.
